# Minecraft Scoreboard Item give Tag Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to give an item a tag in Minecraft 1.11, but it shows me this error:

```
The dataTag does not match for 4be19781-14d9-467c-ba54-d574273e095c
```

The commands I'm using are:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add T1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:tnt",Count:1}}
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add T2 {Item:{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

When testing for NBT data, you need to match exactly, including the data's type.

As `Count` is a byte rather than an integer, you need to append `b`:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add T1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:tnt",Count:1b}}

/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add T2 {Item:{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:1b}}
```